# Wanted to write \r to a file using python

Tags: python

I wanted to write a file with content as following

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ssh-copy-id -i /home/admin/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no admin@XX.XX.XX.XX
expect "admin@XX.XX.XX.XX's password:"
send "password\r"
interact
```

My code is

```py
f=open("/tmp/sshkeycopy.sh", "wb")
f.writelines("""#!/usr/bin/expect\nspawn ssh-copy-id -i /home/admin/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no admin@"""+ip+"""\nexpect \"admin@"""+ip+"""'s password:\"\nsend \"adminpw\r"\"\ninteract""")
```

When I give `\r` to write I get a control charter in the output as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ssh-copy-id -i /home/admin/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no admin@XX.XX.XX.XX
expect "admin@XX.XX.XX.XX's password:"
send "adminpwend**"^M"**"
interact
```

Instead of `^M` I need `\r` to be written to the file..

Comment: try escaping `\r` to `\\r`

Comment: Thanks zamir it worked, Don't know why it was not taking it before..

Comment: To avoid passing password. Better to do ssh private public key configuration. Put public key one remote machine and use private key to login. If your system configurarion can allow.

Comment: Thanks Siddharth for bringing it up , I was just trying in my local machine..

Answer (score 0):

maybe using raw strings is your solution

input:

```
print(r'"password\r"')
```

output:

```
"password\r"
```

Soo, try this:

```
f=open("/tmp/sshkeycopy.sh", "wb")
pass = r'"password\r"'
string = """#!/usr/bin/expect\nspawn ssh-copy-id -i /home/admin/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no admin@"""+ip+"""\nexpect \"admin@"""+ip+"""'s password:""" + pass + """\"\nsend \"adminpw\r"\"\ninteract"""

f.writelines("""#!/usr/bin/expect\nspawn ssh-copy-id -i /home/admin/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no admin@"""+ip+"""\nexpect \"admin@"""+ip+"""'s password:\"\nsend \"adminpw\r"\"\ninteract""")
```